# Android extract string resource from layout xml file

Tags: android, adt

I try to extract hardcoded strings from xml file but always got an error.
Select hardcoded text, ctrl+1 , extract android string and this error pops instead of Android Extract String pop-up.

"The attribute android:text does not accept a string reference"...

Why do i get this error any tips?

I work with eclipse 3.7.1 and adt v16, operating system windows 7.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBcCt.jpg)

Added video that shows the feature 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Oq05KqjXTvs#t=1881s

Answer (score 0):

I just found how to activate this feature.

Simply press **"crtl+1"** and the menu will pop out.

I was searching for this feature too until i found your post....

Thank you for the video too.

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do but i'd like to give you some tips and I hope that this is going to answer your question.

First you should write any Strings which do not change at runtime in your project/res/value/strings.xml

An strings.xml entry example:

```
    <string name="text_button">Any Text</string>
```

Now you can access this string in your XML like that:

```
    android:text="@string/text_button" />
```

However, you'd like to access this string at runtime? Then try this:

```
TextView tv_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
String myText = tv_1.getText();
```

And read this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: Thanks for tip but it is not what i am looking for.http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Oq05KqjXTvs#t=1881s watch for a minute.

Comment: Good generic tip, but not applicable to the question as they are specifically asking about an Eclipse error