# Trouble using Extract Android String in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, refactoring

For some reason, I am always displayed the following error message when highlighting the string value in a TextView and selecting Refactor ==> Android ==> Extract Android String. Any clue how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302636/android-extract-string-resource-from-layout-xml-file

Comment: refactor > android > extract works for me btw. Ctrl+1 or right click & select "Quickfix" from the menu => extract string if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extract in Eclipse is not powerful, and the ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development. I suggest you should migrate to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) as soon as possible. For more details about Android Studio, see the [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) guide.

Android studio released stable version 1.0 today, is the official Android IDE right now. Suggest for all Android developer.:)